Which tense should be used for the verb "promise" in "But you ___!"?
Which tense is most appropriate in this context for the verb "promise"?

— I'm afraid I can't go with you.
— But you ______!
The options given are:

A. promised
B. have promised
C. had promised


PS：One point of contention in this discussion was whether the present perfect tense (Option B) could absolutely never be used to fill in the blank as the correct answer.

C is nonsense - Past Perfect requires a narrative context already set in the past, so it can refer to an action taken earlier than that, but from the speaker's point of view, he's speaking in the Present, not the Past. B is syntactically valid, but idiomatically unlikely because it's a pointlessly complex tense. As is usually the case, when in doubt choose the simplest verb form that makes sense - in this case, Simple Past = A.

@FumbleFingers Not necessarily. Context is everything.

The most natural tense would be the simple past: "But you promised!"
There is an event in the past: "You promised to come with me" so use past tense.
There would be no mistake in using past perfect, especially if contracted "you'd promised", but no particular reason to use past perfect.  Present perfect would not be natural; the speaker refers to a particular promise at a particular time.

Scenario 1: The father had previously promised to accompany his son to the movies but later decided to retract that promise. Consequently, the son was informed of this change and felt disappointed.
Scenario 2: The father made a promise to go to the movies with his son, yet he remains hesitant about attending due to his busy schedule. The son, an avid film enthusiast, is aware of his father's indecisiveness but continues to insist on going to the movies.
Based on the scenarios above, which of the alternatives — "promised," "had promised," or "have promised" — makes the most sense? Thank you!

@Yhin: These  nuanced details should have been provided as part of the question.

@Yhlin  As I said, there is no particular reason given in your question to use the past perfect.  If you add context you might add a reason. However, there's no mistake in just using the past tense in the scenarios you mention, and most speakers wouldn't even notice if they inserted the " 'd " that signifies past perfect.

@Yhlin I addressed every one of those questions in my answer. As I said, you can disregard the downvote.

I'm afraid I can't go with you. — But you ______!
A. promised
B. have promised
C. had promised
Both A and B are possible.  C is out; we are in a current conversation and hence shouldn’t bring in the past perfect.
There's very little difference between A and B.
Although the simple past is normally used to describe an event that has passed and may not have relevance to the present, using it here is fine.  We don't need the present perfect as if it is the only tool to demonstrate the relevance of promise.
In fact, But you promised sounds stronger an objection than But you have promised.
Edit
This responds to the OP’s additional queries in the comments.
Scenario 1
The son heard ealier about this change of mind.   So the conversation would not start with the dad saying
I'm afraid ...
It may instead start with the son saying
So you've decided (or you decided) not to go, but you ... me.
Here, promised works; had promised doesn’t work for have decided but works for decided;
have promised works for have decided but is clumsy.  It doesn't work for decided.
Scenario 2
The conversation may start with
You're still undecided about the outing, but you ... me.
All is in the present, and the answer is the same as the original example's: promised works; had promised doesn't; have promised works.

Scenario 1: The father had previously promised to accompany his son to the movies but later decided to retract that promise. Consequently, the son was informed of this change and felt disappointed. Scenario 2: The father made a promise to go to the movies with his son, yet he remains hesitant about attending due to his busy schedule. The son, an avid film enthusiast, is aware of his father's indecisiveness but continues to insist on going to the movies. Based on the scenarios above, which of the alternatives — "promised," "had promised," or "have promised" — makes the most sense? Thanks a lot!

Hi, @user583787, I have added the two scenarios to my answer.

Hello, @Seowjooheng, Many thanks for your time and help-_-

Consider these scenarios, where a father/ husband is unable to keep his promise due to financial constraints:
Dialogue 1: Father-son conversation.
Father promised to buy his son a car on his 21st birthday
Son : "But you had promised to buy me a car! I've been waiting for months.
Dialogue 2: Husband-wife conversation.
Husband promised his wife a diamond necklace on their 10th anniversary.
Wife: But you had promised to buy me a diamond necklace!
"But you had promised" is a phrase often used to express disappointment or frustration when someone hasn't kept a commitment  they made earlier. It implies that there was an expectation based on a previous promise, and that expectation hasn't been met.
When a promise is broken, it implies that the promise was made in the past but not fulfilled. To express this, you would use the past perfect tense "had promised" instead of the present perfect tense "have promised".
Now let's look at the original conversation:

— I'm afraid I can't go with you.
— But you ______!
The options given are:
A. promised.
B. have promised.
C. had promised.

An exclamatory sentence shows strong emotions or feelings, such as excitement, surprise, anger, or joy.
The sentence beginning with "but" and ending in an exclamation mark justifies "had promised" as the most appropriate choice.
Edit-1.
Reference comment - Is it correct to use the Present Perfect Tense.
Consider the example :
If the occasion (like the wedding anniversary) is over and the promise was not kept, the past simple or past perfect would usually be preferred to indicate that the opportunity to fulfill the promise has passed:
"You promised/ had promised to buy a diamond necklace on our wedding anniversary.".
However,  using the present perfect stresses the disappointment of the broken promise in the present.
"You have promised to buy a diamond necklace on our wedding anniversary, but you didn’t."

No, the simple past is best here.

There is nothing wrong in using "simple past" or "past perfect. As it is an exclamatory sentence (strong feelings) By using the past perfect tense "had promised," the son emphasizes that:

The promise was made before (establishing a prior commitment).
The promise was not kept (highlighting the father's failure to fulfill it).


There's nothing wrong with the present perfect either. The exclamatory idea is just an opinion and not about grammar.


They've promised to come on time. We are waiting for them. 2. They had promised to come  on time but they arrived late (promise broken so past perfect)


That is very different. The fact is that all three tenses can be used, but in this context, the probability is that the simple past is best. Please read my answer and James' answer.

@Jammes Mathai  Thank you for your sharing!

@Lambie，thank you, Lambie.

@Yhlin If you have the most appropriate answer suggested by the book, please share it. I don't understand why there should be such opposition to the use of the Past Perfect Tense. It is there in Grammar to be used. You have mentioned scenarios in your comment

@James Mathai, Hello, James!
This question arose from a discussion about the following grammar choice problem:
—I'm afraid I can't go with you.
—But you ______!
Options are:
A. promised
B. have promised
The question doesn't provide any additional context for the dialogue. What do you think is the most appropriate option between A and B? One point of contention in this discussion was whether the present perfect tense (Option B) could absolutely never be used to fill in the blank as the correct answer。

@james Mathai, Hi, James,  in the book by Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, he suggests that the past tense is utilized to express a belief that has just been proven true or false. He provides examples including :
But you promised...! (NOT but you have promised....!).

@Yhlin I also thought Present Perfect Tense should not be used. But it can be used. It's a good point - One point of contention in this discussion was whether the present perfect tense (Option B) could absolutely never be used to fill in the blank as the correct answer. You can edit and include it in your question. I have edited and explained in my answer

@james Mathai, Appreciate it!

@Yhlin This is not about "the correct" answer. This is about how people might actually speak. Yes, the MOST likely is the simple past but there are a number of other possibilities. And I don't really see how the sample dialogue "expresses a belief that has just been proven true or false".

— I'm afraid I can't go with you.
— But you ______!
SIMPLE PAST
But you promised!
At one point in time, the father promised this to the kid.
Compare:
PRESENT PERFECT
— I'm afraid I can't go with you.
— But you have promised this to me (in the past)!
In the past, we don't know when, the father has promised this to the kid.
One of the most difficult uses of present perfect is that it refers to something in the past which is not one point in time and is not defined. It just signals the past.
PAST PERFECT
— I'm afraid I can't go with you.
— But you'd promised before we left on vacation!
The past perfect has to be preceded by something in the simple past but this would not likely be the case here. However, it is an accurate sentence.
In other words, this question is really about using the simple past, the present perfect or the past perfect here. They all can work but the simple past is the most likely.
In fact, one might even hear this sort of thing:
SON COMPLAINS TO FATHER
You've been promising me for weeks that we could go fishing.
You promised me three weeks in a row, in fact. Every Sunday.
Why would you be promising me this if you don't plan to do it?
If I'd [had] promised something like that to my son, I'd [would] stick to the plan. I guess, though, if I keep complaining, you won't be promising me stuff like this in the future.

thank you for your insights！

@Yhlin I tried to give you a full picture. Disregard the downvote. Unless you compare one with another, you won't really understand it.

@Lambie I dont know who downvoted both our answers.

@JamesMathai Dunno. There are those with ill intentions...
