Past Tense or Present Perfect Tense
everyone
I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently exploring Michael Swan's Practical English Usage (PEU), and I've encountered a concept that's left me puzzled.
Swan explains that we utilize the past tense to express a belief that has just been proven true or false. He provides examples such as:

It's not as big as I expected. (NOT it's not as big as I have expected.)
You're older than I thought. (NOT you're older than I have thought.)
But you promised...! (NOT but you have promised....!)
I knew you would help me! (NOT I have known you would help me!)

Given this theory from Swan, I'd like to revisit my past post and ask for your assistance:

I'm afraid I can't go with you.
But you ______!
A.promised B.have promised C.had promised

Is 'promised' the only correct verb form to use according to Swan's PEU, and would 'have promised' be incorrect in this context? I'd greatly appreciate any insights you can offer!

We can’t know what “Swan’s theory” is because, although you describe it (loosely) and say things about it, you don’t quote his entire statement of it. So you’ve not provided enough information for us to confidently judge correctness “according to Swan’s theory.”

But perhaps it was not your intention to constrain our judgments of correctness to comply with “Swan’s theory”? Maybe what you meant was something like, “Given Swan’s guidance, I now wonder if option A is the only one that’s viable”?

And questions really should be complete and self-contained. As it’s currently expressed, yours requires readers to know something about some earlier question.

I agree with James's answer to your previous question, that "You promised" is by far the most natural  response.

Swan does not say 'promised' is the only correct verb form to use, nor does he say 'have promised' is incorrect. What he says, which is perfectly true, is that we don't normally use the Perfect form in such contexts. Why are so many learners obsessed with finding places where they can use Perfect verb forms? The sensible approach is to always prefer the simplest verb form that's acceptable.

In preceding text, Swan says ...we usually prefer a past tense [i.e. - Simple Past, not Present Perfect] when we identify the person, thing or circumstances responsible for a present situation.

Any parent will know that the only answer is You promised!.

@FumbleFingers: Why the obsession? My theory is because in some languages, for example German and French, speakers of these languages use the present perfect in situations where English uses the simple past. In these languages the simple past (aka the preterite) is really only used in literary or very formal language.

I upvoted because this question shows research and effort. Perhaps a note about languages such as Italian that would use the present perfect instead of the simple past (see @Billy Kerr's insightful comment). You could... copy and paste the research, i.e. M. Swan's guidelines, in a new answer, questioners can post their own answers,  OR copy and paste it in the old question. It would not change the essence of your question.

English "prefers" simplicity. We don't have the complexity of gender, and  we only have a handful of "irregular" verbs left - the only reason we've still got even those is because be, do, go, see, have,... are used so often it's difficult to change them. Note that linguists tend to say English actually only has 2 verb tenses (Present and "not-Present"). Everything else is handled by the auxiliary verbs, performing a "function words" job similar to the way English makes extensive use of prepositions (where other languages might impose morphological changes on "content words").

I answered your other question and you did not respond. So, this is a duplicate with the other question. Depending on what you actually mean, more than one tense can be used. BUT we need complete context. That said, I addressed the You promised question in detail. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/358571/which-tense-should-be-used-for-the-verb-promise-in-but-you/358616#358616

Dear all, your explanations were incredibly clear and helped me grasp the intricacies of the issue. Thank you once again for your patient guidance.
